# What does @[arguments] mean in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

What does the `@[arguments]` syntax in a makefile mean? For example, I have come across a makefile that contains the following:

```
all: $(EXEC_NAME)
   @[ -p video_fifo ] || mkfifo video_fifo
```

What does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. You are parsing it incorrectly.

The leading `@` is for make. It means "silence this command". See [Recipe Echoing](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing) in the GNU make manual.

The rest of the line is a shell script. In this case it starts with a test `[ -p video_fifo ]` (you often see this in the context of an `if` statement `if [ -n "$var" ]` or whatever see [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test) for more about `[`/`test` and for the `-p` flag) and then `|| mkfifo video_fifo` to create the `video_fifo` fifo if the `[` test returns false (hence the `||` OR operator).

Comment: So what that line does is it makes video_fifo if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Correct. If `video_fifo` is a fifo then `[ -p video_fifo ]` returns true and the line is finished (the `||`/OR short-circuits and is done). If it doesn't exist or isn't a fifo then the test returns false and the right-hand side of the `||` is run to create the fifo (which will fail I imagine if some other non-fifo file is there but that's probably not likely).